# Can I install a ground bar in an 8x8 junction box for splicing cables?

Tags: electrical, grounding, junction-box

I had a sub panel put in a few years ago but recently upgraded our panel. My county inspector said I could splice the short wires to get them inside the panel.

I bought [a box](https://www.lowes.com/pd/WIEGMANN-SC-Gray-Metal-Weatherproof-New-Work-Standard-Enclosure-Wall-Electrical-Box/50311355) and I have 8 circuits going through it. Can I install a ground bar or do I need to pigtail all these circuits?

Seems like I need to pigtail or crimp in my research but would be a simpler and cleaner. I have access to a ground rod that I could connect the bus to. All the circuits enter in a crawl space. No conduit.

Thanks

Comment: What wiring method is being run from the box in question back to the panel, and what make/manufacturer of box did you buy?

Comment: It’s in a joist bay in a crawl space and wires run the wall cavity to the panel. I have access to the grounding rod other wise I’d just pig tail these. 

It’s the exact same box linked in op but it’s 8x8x4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the grounds with a wire-nut chain or with a ground bar... except grounds *must* go to the metal box. That is, the metal box must be included in the grounding.  I would mount a ground bar inside the box.

My strongly preferred way to do this is to use EMT metal conduit or RMC coupler(s) between box and panel.   In that case, the metal conduit itself provides the ground.   You only need pairs of THHN wires (though they do need to be identified), my go-to for that is colored electrical tape. The standard $5 5-pack of colored tape gives many possible combinations using 2 colors.

If the conduit runs are 2 feet or longer, only 4 circuits are allowed per pipe.   But putting in multiple pipes isn't much harder than 1.

I think a ground bar mounted on the box would be an elegant way of dealing with that.  Technically metal box + (non-flexible) metal conduit = the box carries the ground, however since the bar-box connection is improvised, I would run 1 ground wire to remove all question of *how* the ground bar is mounted to the box. (for electrical connection must be tapped -32 screws or finer and #8 or larger, so 8-32 or 10-32).  Even if the conduit was PVC, the installation is allowed to share 1 ground wire (of the largest size) from box to panel.

**This does not work with neutrals. Every circuit needs its own neutral!**  (MWBCs are one circuit sharing 2 hots).

Comment: I recall an answer noting that any kind of system used to organize splices in a box may *not* be mounted to the box.   Is there an exception for a ground bus, or are we relying on the "excuse" that the connection is the *required* electrical connection between grounds and box, and the fact it looks like a tidy, rigid bus mounted on the box is just a coincidence?

Comment: Interesting. Because of timing I ran the the circuits temporarily with Romex from the box to the panel. I should have asked this question before doing that, would have been much easier your way. 

I’ll run the ground bar so at least it’s half the grounding. Very informative answer though, thank you.

Comment: @jay613 -- UL listed grounding bars fall under KDER (Grounding and Bonding Equipment), which means they aren't subject to the issue of "you can't mount splices to a box" that splicing connectors in category ZMVV are

Comment: @Kdemand well there's nothing wrong with doing it all in Romex.  It actually saves you a bit of marking since the Romex cable naturally groups the wires.  However you still need to tie all the grounds to the metal box. I'm not sure how an inspector would view connecting only some of the box-panel grounds, though.